# Talend Open Studio : timpala component missing

Tags: etl, talend, impala, data-integration

I am using Talend Open Studio for data integration.
When I create a new connection to an impala database, it works, I can even find the tables, but I can't add this component in the current job, I get this error:

```
Cannot apply drag and drop operation on this component currently.
```

If I import a project using an impala component, it says that this component is missing.
According to the documentation, I should install the timpala component, but I don't have this option.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Talend open studio for data Integration, the impala components exist only in "Talend open studio for big data" and "Talend data fabric".

You can see the component compatibility matrix here :
https://www.talendforge.org/components/index.php

And this is written in the documentation of impala component :
https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/7.3/impala/timpalaconnection-standard-properties